# Simpleurl type external data sources do not support authentication

Tags: integration, lightning-connect

Wanted to try out External Data objects and created a data source with the free and publicly available OData Test Service from services.odata.org

When I "Validate and Synch" I get the following confused error message:

"Simpleurl type external data sources do not support authentication"

Which does not make sense since I have:

- Type: Simple URL
- URL: `http://services.odata.org/V3/(S(ioxcmsdqq4jmw5hug3ybtxbu))/OData/OData.svc/`
- Identity Type=Anonymous
- Authentication Protocol=No Authentication

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Lightning Connect OData v2 external data source type to connect to an OData data source.  Simple URL is used with Chatter Files which doesn't use validate and sync.

Comment: Simple URL is the only type of Data Source I can create.  It's a full-copy sandbox of an "unlimited" org. What am I missing?

Comment: Lightning Connect is an addon SKU that doesn't come with any org except DE orgs. If you have Lightning Connect on the org your sandbox was copied from, the sandbox should have it. If it doesn't, I would suggest consulting your account rep to have the license reapplied.

Comment: OK managed to solve it by getting a DEV Org and using a slightly modifed URL (SalesForce demands OData v2):  http://services.odata.org/V2/(S(ioxcmsdqq4jmw5hug3ybtxbu))/OData/OData.svc/